# Prevent remote cmd window from closing

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, restart, psexec

So I am working on rebooting a remote computer. Psexec is not installed on the remote machine so my usual cmds won't work. After tinkering a while I was able to get the reboot to go through by using:

```
runas /netonly /user:DOMAIN\USERNAME "shutdown -m \\XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -r -f -t 0"
```

That works just fine about 99% of the time the issue being that the cmd window that it spawns closes immediately upon execution so there is no chance to see the error code that it returns.

I understand using cmd /k, pause, pinging 127 etc can all be using to hold open local cmd windows, but what can I do to keep a remote window open.

Comment: You do not need psexec installed on a remote computer to target executing on a remote computer. Just need file and printer sharing enabled on the remote computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute several commands remotely:

- pause always: `runas ..... "cmd /c shutdown ........ & pause"`
- pause in case of error: `runas ..... "cmd /c shutdown ........ & if errorlevel 1 pause"`

Comment: Excellent, with a little tweaking I ended up with:

`runas /netonly /user:DOMAIN\USERNAME "cmd /c shutdown -m \\X.X.X.X -r -f -t 0 & echo Reboot Error Level: %errorlevel% & @pause"

This executes the reboot the hold there giving me a chance to review, making sure it worked.

Comment: @tapman displays `Reboot Error Level: 0` always as currently written. Try e.g. with a non-existing command `runas /user:%username% "cmd /c XshutXdown  & echo Error: %errorlevel% & pause"`. You need [Delayed Expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) as follows: `runas /user:%username% "cmd /V /c XshutXdown & echo Error: !errorlevel! & pause"`. See also `cmd /?`